Invalid integer in property "price" (in "offers")
I've created structured data for Car (car rental website) and Google Search Console is throwing this error:
Invalid integer in property "price" (in "offers")

for this piece of code
            'offers' => [
            '@type' => 'Offer',
            'price' => number_format($car->daily_rate, 2, '.', ''),
            'priceCurrency' => 'EUR',
            'availability' => 'https://schema.org/InStock',
        ],

What should I be doing differently?
Regards.

You should probably provide an actual integer - instead of a number formatted with a decimal point and two digits after that.

number_format($car->daily_rate, 2, '.', '') creates something like 1234.00 wheras the schema expects an integer, ie 1234 So there are two possiblities: (1) Provide a value according to the schema or (2) change the schema to accept also decimals.

what is the value of $car->daily_rate provide the actual markup giving the error, and also add more context (is this merchant or something else)

@derpirscher the issue is that schema.org validator does not throw it as an error.
I tried as 'price' => (string) $car->daily_rate, but it would still throw the error.
The overall issue is that I have prices like 3.25 or 7.92 so if I return integers I have to round that up.

@traynor the value is: 35.47 I run a car rental marketplace https://cria.al, if you validate using schema.org it won't give an error for type Car/Offer. My prices as said before are with decimals so I can't really return an integer without rounding up the price.

on your site, the number is actually given as a string "99.99", you could try adding it as a number, but it doesn't seem to help, it still complains if it's floating, which it shouldn't, because price can be a Number

The only thing that solves this is: 'price' => round((float)$car->daily_rate),
Do you guys think there is another option except "Vehicle listing" to be used for rental cars? as this seems to work only for car sales?
